# The payment method of using phonegap in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I heard that the UiWebView for payment in iPhone app will be reject. Is it really true? If yes, how can I use a valid one for payment if I want to have credit card payment.

Answer (score 0):

If the item you are purchasing is virtual(like guns, ammo) then you need to use inApp purchase but if you are purchasing physical stuffs. Then you can use paypal or any other purchasing media.